# Mobile First Platform 6.3: Direct Update service JSON Error on Android

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am getting the following error on android when using the direct update service.

**WL_DIRECT_UPDATE_MANAGER startUpdate error JSON error**

I am using the default listener of worklight.js. The same code works fine on iOS and updates are successfully deployed. Would really appreciate any pointers.

I have not defined wl_directUpdateRealm in an customSecurity or mobileSecurity test. Do I need this?

Reason for this last question is it works fine on iOS without the realm added.

Comment: You should add the logcat output. Also when is this happening? When direct update happens? Before the update or after the update?

Comment: srujan, please supply a custom project where this is happening and that we could debug.

Comment: Mention if this happening only to a specific Android model/device/OS version or to all Android.

Comment: @IdanAdar, This is on all android devices. will supply custom project

Comment: @IdanAdar, please use below link to download sample project. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lxxb4mt4wjdclk/sampleproject.zip?dl=0

Comment: Something is very wrong with your main.js - it is like you copied it into the common\js folder after it was generated into a native folder... -- this is not the issue here. Just an observation.

Answer (score 0):

Something is very wrong in this sample application that you have provided.

1. This is not a sample app - it's the full app.
   If I create a new application and test Direct Update, it is working out-of-the-box
2. common\js\main.js - this file is not the original main.js. That is, it appears to me you have copied the main.js from the native folder into the common folder. The evidence to that is the following comment lines in the file:

/* JavaScript content from js/main.js in folder common */

/* JavaScript content from js/main.js in folder android */
// This method is invoked after loading the main HTML and successful initialization of the Worklight runtime.

/* JavaScript content from js/main.js in folder iphone */
// This method is invoked after loading the main HTML and successful initialization of the Worklight runtime.

Something in your development flow is Wrong.
Correct it and try again.

Comment: I have tried the sample app which was provided in the IBM knowledge center. On first attempt sample app works fine, after adding public signing key it gives "FAILURE_UNZIPPING" error. After this again, I have downloaded sample project from IBM site. In this project there is no public signing key where this works fine. Both are identical except signing key in the application-descriptor. xml file. Not sure why I am getting FAILURE_UNZIPPING error when both projects are identical. here I am uploading both projects, let me know if I am missing anything in this process.

Comment: Custom Projects: 1) https://www.dropbox.com/s/ii1symc9swt2mrn/CustomDirectUpdate_doesn%27t_work.zip?dl=0   2)https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3hxdewk4vp1jbg/CustomDirectUpdate_works_fine.zip?dl=0

Comment: 1) You must correct the errors in your project that I have mentioned. Your app is in bad shape. 2) If you remove the public signing from your application, does it work? 3) Why do you not mention these details beforehand, that you are trying to add direct update protection. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi Idan, 1) Even after cleaning code we are getting the "startupdate error json error". 2) No clue why update alert is popping up before connecting to worklight server. 3) This behavior is only in andoird devices(all). 4) In iphone I can connect to worklight server and i can send updates to connected devices.